# Jquery Autocomplete not working with extra white spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, javascript-objects

I have implemented autocomplete suggestions, it works perfectly, but when i type 2 or more space at staring or between words then , autocomplete not showing me dropdown suggestions list. Please help me . thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
$( "#input" ).autocomplete({
 source: tags_suggetions,
 appendTo: "#appendToHere",
 select: function(event, ui) {
 selectedItem = ui.item.value;
 document.getElementById("input").value = selectedItem;
 $("#searchBtn").click();
 }
});
```

Comment: `str = str.replace(/ +(?= )/g,'');` Clear multiple whitespaces with a method like this. After all, this does not matching with fuzzy logic. Therefore, it searches for an exact match.

Comment: thanks for comment, i tried this but still not working. any solution plz?